# how to test microservice using spring boot and maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, testing, microservices

I am using spring boot and maven framework to set up microservice. 
Now i want to do some tests to make sure they are working properly.
However, I am not sure how i should invoke them when i run the test.
Or is my way of testing micro service correct?
Thanks in advance

i have tried to invoke the micro services in the test java file but failed

this is the interface

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
...
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert into Employee (id,fullname) values (:id,:fullname)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    void insertEmployee(@Param("id") int id,@Param("fullname") String fullname);
...
}
```

this is the class that handles mappings

```
public class EmployeeResource {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository usersRepository;
    @PostMapping(value="/add")
    @Transactional
    public void add(...){...}
}
```

I tried to invoke them by using this but failed because database is not updated

1

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testInsert(){
        EmployeeResource er = new EmployeeResource();
        er.add(999,"test");
    ArrayList<Employee> test = (ArrayList<Employee>)er.find(999);


    }
```

2

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testInsert(){
        EmployeeRepository usersRepository;
        usersRepository.insertEmployee(999,"test");
    ArrayList<Employee> test = 
        (ArrayList<Employee>)usersRepository.findEmp(999);


    }
```

Comment: You should configure a datasource for testing purposes, take a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Comment: Use PostMan rest client to test some end points of your microservice.

Comment: @Sambit manually testing end points is a bad idea and not reproducible way to test.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of creating microservices is "How these microservices will communicate with each other?"
You are missing to include "Spring Cloud features" here to establish communication between different microservices. 
**Please read following things in Spring Cloud:
Spring Cloud config server, Eureka Naming server, Zuul API Gateway, Ribbon, Hystrix etc.**

You can refer following link for study:
https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springcloud

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. I realized that i can use @SpringBootTest to do the integration test.